# Sum and show once a product in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created a table with production data in SSRS
If I select one week in  the report then it dos not do a sum up the individual products

I would like to sum up products for each datetime.
How can I do this? It should show me a result only once line for each product.

Comment: What are the columns? Do you want the sum of the 3 columns for each of M101 ... M113?

Comment: What is the query you are using for this report?

Comment: @pavel yes a sum of the 3 columns for each of M101... I did a sum at the end of this table of all the data but I would like to have a sum for each Machines depends on date. the table shall show me only once a Machine Name

Comment: @mayo, did you add Datum as a Rows Group?

Comment: shall I add this in my expression:  OVER(PARTITION BY [intervaldate])

Comment: @mayo, If you have to get the Total for Maschine1, Maschine2 and Maschine3 for every Datum you have to group by that field. Select any cell of the tablix and in the bottom of surface in a panel says `Row Groups` drag and drop Datum to that panel. If you need further help include in your question more details about what you are expecting.

Comment: I would like to have a sum for example of the month december not for every day. I would like to have a sum of choosen date

Comment: Add an example of the tablix you are expecting, I don't get how you will achieve that based on the tables you put in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct You want to group by `Name` but you can select the date range of your report.

Using this dataset I've recreated your scenario and created your expected tablix.

[image]

> Note there are two different `Datum` values and `Name` values is
>   repeated across the date range.

Using this tablix with the following data arrangement.

[image]

It will produce this tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the column intervaldate in your group by, you'll never see the the column "Units" as you wish because all the dates will appear into your result. To do the result as you want, you need to remove the intervaldate from the select and the group by, for sure. So, your query should be like that...

```
SELECT * FROM (tsystem.Name as Name, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Maschine 1' THEN Units else 0 end) AS Maschine1,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Maschine 2' THEN Units else 0 end) AS Maschine2,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Maschine 3' THEN Units else 0 end) AS Maschine3
FROM Count inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.id
WHERE IntervalDate BETWEEN @StartDateTime AND @EndDateTime
AND tsystem.Name IN ('M101'
     , 'M102'
     , 'M103'
     , 'M104'
     , 'M105'
     , 'M107'
     , 'M109'
     , 'M110'
     , 'M111'
     , 'M113'
     , 'M114'
     , 'M115')
GROUP BY tsystem.Name) AS s
```

THis could be done using a pivot because the "machine names" is a column. This will avoid the subquery and the case statement. You can see more about the pivot [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: but if I remove intervaldate then this error appears: ...IntervalDate is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the Group by clause

Comment: Executing the query that I've posted you recieve the error? Make sure that you're using exactly like I've posted @mayo